# Firestore Null Pointer Exception on firestoreoptions.getService

Tags: java, linux, google-cloud-firestore, smartfoxserver

Hi i am using SmartFoxServer with a Java extension. Inside that extension i am trying to get firestore instance. Below is the code i am using to connect to service that is working fine inside IDE (Eclipse). but when i deploy my extension on SmartFoxServer it gives a null pointer exception on firestoreOptions.getService

```
String jsonPath = "data/************.json";
        GoogleCredentials credentials = null;
            try {
                credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
                        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                trace("Exception" + e1.toString());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                trace("Exception" + e1.toString());
            }

            FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build();

            Firestore db = firestoreOptions.getService();
            this.db = db;
            try {
                run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                trace("Exception : " + e);
            }
```

Here is the exception i am getting.

```
    com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException:
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Exception: com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException
Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
Description: Extension initialization failed.
+--- --- ---+
Stack Trace:
+--- --- ---+
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException.networkException(FirestoreException.java:70)
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:81)
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:71)
com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:506)
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.getFirestoreRpc(FirestoreOptions.java:306)
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.<init>(FirestoreImpl.java:76)
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:62)
com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:55)
com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:493)
sfs2x.extension.game.quiz.QuizExtension.init(QuizExtension.java:159)
com.smartfoxserver.v2.entities.managers.SFSExtensionManager.createExtension(SFSExtensionManager.java:303)
com.smartfoxserver.v2.entities.managers.SFSZoneManager.createZone(SFSZoneManager.java:426)
```

i am new to firestore. Don't know if any jar file/library is missing to run this code on server. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `credentials` object is correctly initialized?

Comment: Yes. I have checked by logging credentials object. It has correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

environment variable must be added with the correct credential's file path and name to run firestore on server.